# How to overwrite a macro definition using compiler options

Tags: c, macros, compiler-options, undef

I want to redefine a macro, without modifying the header or source files.

For example:
#define macro_1 Present -- Is what actually defined in the header file

For one set of execution I need this macro to be same as it is , but for another set of execution I need the macro to be redefined to value 'Absent'
This should be done without changing the header file.
Am using the ghs compliler.

I tried undef option but its not effectively working

Answer (score 1):

For GCC or Clang, the option to define a macro on the command line is `-D`. As in `-D macro_1=\"Absent\"`.

You need to use conditional-compilation in the header file though:

```
#ifndef macro_1
# define macro_1 "Present"
#endif
```

Otherwise you will get macro redefinition errors.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not possible with most compilers if the code doesn't already contain `#ifndef macro_1` or similar.

If it does, then see the answer by.Some programmer dude.